How many pairs $(B, C)$ of such sets exist?
Suppose that $A = \{a, b, c\}$ and that we're choosing two subsets $B, C$ of $A$ so that $B\cap C = \emptyset$. How many pairs $(B, C)$ of such sets exist?
If $|B| = |C| = 2$, then there must be a common element in both, in which case $B\cap C\neq \emptyset$.
$$B = \{a, b\}\space\space C = \{c\}$$
$$B = \{b, c\}\space\space C = \{a\}$$
$$B = \{a, c\}\space\space C = \{b\}$$
$$B = \{a\}\space\space C = \{b, c\}$$
$$B = \{b\}\space\space C = \{a, c\}$$
$$B = \{c\}\space\space C = \{a, b\}$$
$$B = \emptyset\space\space  C\subseteq A$$
$$B\subseteq A\space\space C = \emptyset$$
$$B = C = \emptyset$$
Is this reasonable?

Given that $A$ consist of just $3$ elements you can easily list all the possibilities.

You are missing solutions of the form $B={a}$, $C={b}$, for instance.

General approach:  for each element $x\in A$, you can choose to put $x$ in $B,C$ or Neither.

If $B=\phi$ then you have 8 choices for $C$ ($C=\{a,b,c\},\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{b,c\},\{a\},\{b\},\{c\}$ or $C=\phi$).
If $|B|=1$ (3 such choices) then there are four choices for $C$.
For example, if $B=\{a\}$ then you can choose $C=\phi,\{b\}, \{c\}$ or $\{bc\}$
This makes a total of $3\times 4=12$ possibilities with $|B|=1$
If $|B|=2$ (3 such choices) then there are two choices for $C$.
For example if $b=\{a,b\}$ we can choose $C=\{c\}$ or $C=\phi$
This makes a total of $3\times 2=6$ possibilities with $|B|=2$
And finally if $|B|=3$ then $B=\{a,b,c\}$ and the only choice for $C$ is $C=\phi$
So the total number of $(B,C)$ pairs is $8+12+6+1=27$
